# Breaking of a periodic $\pm1$ sequence into positive and negative parts.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let $A_n=(a_1,a_2,\dots)$ be a periodic sequence of $a_i=\pm1$, the period of length $2n$ containing equal numbers of positive and negative terms. The period is assumed to be irreducible, so that $2n$ is its least possible value.

Let a sequence of length $n $ be termed positive if all partial sums
$$
S_k=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i,\quad k=1..n
$$
are non-negative, and negative if all partial sums are non-positive.

The question: is it always possible to choose $i$ $(1\le i\le 2n)$, such that the sequence $(a_i,a_{i+1},\dots,a_{i+n-1})$ is positive, and the sequence 
$a_{i+n},a_{i+1},\dots,a_{i+2n-1}$ is negative?

It seems to be true for small values of $n$, but I do not see how to prove this in general case. I could also overlook some counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your requirements, then I think the sequence with $n = 5$ and initial period $(+1,+1,-1,-1,+1,+1,+1,-1,-1,-1)$ is a counterexample.  The partial sums for the subsequences of length $5$ starting at each index from $1$ to $10$ are listed in this table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|rrrrr|c}
\rm{Index}&S_1&S_2&S_3&S_4&S_5&\rm{Type}\\
\hline
1&1&2&1&0&1&\rm{positive}\\
2&1&0&-1&0&1\\
3&-1&-2&-1&0&1\\
4&-1&0&1&2&1\\
5&1&2&3&2&1&\rm{positive}\\
6&1&2&1&0&-1\\
7&1&0&-1&-2&-1\\
8&-1&-2&-3&-2&-1&\rm{negative}\\
9&-1&-2&-1&0&-1&\rm{negative}\\
10&-1&0&1&0&-1
\end{array}
$$
As you can see, in no case does a negative subsequence appear $5$ steps after a positive subsequence.

I don't know if $n = 5$ is minimal; this sequence was the first thing I tried.

Comment: You are correct. Now I see that my actual problem is more complicated. Thanks!